# Stripe RedirectToCheckout (Deprecated, yes) showing "Mthly Dues" as title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment

I have integrated Stripe.js "RedirectToCheckout" in my React app and everything is working perfectly fine (yes I understand this is deprecated).

My only issue is that it is showing a default title of "Mthly Dues" for where the website/payment is coming from.
[image: Mthly Dues at Checkout??]

Any advice on how to change this to the name of my app "Trend Edge". I'm not seeing a field for this in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout).

Thanks!

Comment: Found it ...

https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/branding

Answer (score 0):

Those branding settings are controlled by the settings in your Stripe account. You'll want to update the public business name that you have set for your account:
https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/public